# pass the dynamic textarea value on button click to javascript-php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i am having a loop of `textarea` which has diferent values and a corresponding `button` to each textarea.

What i need to do is, if i click a button the value in the respective textarea should be alerted using javascript.

Here is the code what i tried:

```
<?php
$a=0;
$b=100;
while($a<5)
{
echo "<textarea id='a'>".$b."</textarea><br/>";
echo "<button onClick='ddd(a.value)'>click</button><br>";
$a++;
$b++;
}
?>
<script>
function ddd(d)
{
    alert(d);
}
</script>
```

But it shows same value (first textarea value) on alert to all button click.

So i changed the id of textarea to dynamic id as

```
echo "<textarea id='$a'>".$b."</textarea><br/>";
    echo "<button onClick='ddd($a.value)'>click</button><br>";
```

But it is not working. It haven't even give any alert message.

How can i achieve this? Is there any other ways? Suggest me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JavaScript identifier cannot start with a number, and `$a` will always be a number.

[Use `document.getElementById` instead of depending on globals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables).